# How to select value from drop-down list in Selenium with li and ul tags?

Tags: html

I am to trying to select value from drop-down list. Not getting any errors with the below code, it just runs and is not selecting any value from the drop-down list. I tried to select the currency value `US Dollar`.

Can anyone help me on this?

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row']/span[1]/span[1]/span[1]/span[2]/span[1]"));
ele.click();

List<WebElement> currencyList=ele.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

for(WebElement li : currencyList)
{       
    if(li.getText().equals("US Dollar"))
    {
        li.click();
        break;          
    }
}
```

```html
<span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="CurrencyId_listbox"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span>
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="CurrencyId_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0" id="a2d90958-fc45-4147-baab-eb040de841b0">US Dollar</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Australian Dollar</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">British Pound</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="3">Canadian Dollar</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="4">Chinese Yuan Renminbi</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="5">Euro</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="6">Hong Kong Dollar</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="7">Japanese Yen</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="8">Russian Rouble</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="9">Swedish Krona</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="10">Ringgit</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="11">Singaporean Dollar</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="12">Indonesian Rupiah</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="13">Myanmar Kyat</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="14">Philippine Peso</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="15">Thai Baht</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
List<WebElement> currencyList= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.k-list.k-reset>li"));
for(WebElement currency:currencyList ){
if(currency.getText().trim().equals("US Dollar"))
currency.click();
}
```

Hope this will help.